# Vertically aligning an icon in a button

Tags: html, css

I am relatively very new to HTML and CSS and I have the following difficulty, see the below HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="arrow-btn">
       about us <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
</a>
```

I have the following CSS:

```
body {
    background: #000;
}
.arrow-btn {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    margin: 50px auto 50px auto;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.arrow-btn:focus , .arrow-btn:active , .arrow-btn:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    margin: 50px auto 50px auto;
}

.arrow-btn > i {
    font-size: .8em;
}

.arrow-btn:hover > i ,  .arrow-btn:active > i ,  .arrow-btn:focus > i{
    -webkit-transition: transform .5s;
    -o-transition: transform .5s;
    transition: transform .5s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
}
```

My difficulty is with vertical alignment. Now since my HTML markup is so tiny, I would prefer not to use the `display:table` solution as that would need additonal markup. I would ideally want my markup to be just as it is, now please notice that I have added the following css to the `.arrow-btn i`:

```
.arrow-btn > i {
    font-size: .8em;
}
```

So how do I vertically align the text in the button to the arrow?

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/obs3es5L/).

Comment: maybe so http://jsfiddle.net/oevvbmz9/

Comment: @Dmitriy And when You set `font-size: .5em;` on `<i>` tag, it breaks. I think, there is no solution to this besides `display: table-cell;`

Comment: @Dmitriy `position:relative` would really be my  last resort LOOL

Comment: It's a bit difficult task as the font families are different. I think it will require some manual adjusting, for example `.fa {transform: translate(0px, -2px);}`

Comment: [Closest I can get](http://jsfiddle.net/obs3es5L/6/). The `outline` is added on purpose to demonstrate why it's unaligned (hint: enlarge the font size of `.arrow-btn > i` to be more clear).

Answer (score 2):

Give the icon a `vertical-align` value and adjust its `line-height` to sit where you want it to relative to the label.

[Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/obs3es5L/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to align the arrow to the button text using `table` and `table-cell`. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/myTerminal/obs3es5L/4/).

Comment: The OP doesn't want to use tables

Comment: @imbondbaby , hey thats ok ! don't downvote this answer ! if i don't have to add additional markup and display:table on the container then i'll consider this answer ! :) thx

Comment: Sorry, missed that. But the fact that the arrow needs to be aligned and not  the button is still valid :)

Comment: I didn't downvote it by the way. i just commented :)